# When using PKCE, are the state and nonce parameters still necessary protection from csrf and code injection?

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

When I'm using the authorization code flow with PKCE do I still need `state` and `nonce`?

For `state` (that prevents **login-csrf**), if an attacker sends me a malicious Authorization Response, the client may accept the response, but in the end no token can be retrieved, as the `code_verifier` would not match the one for the code (as this was generated by the attacker).

For `nonce` the same is valid as far as **CSRF** is concerned.
For **code injection** attacks, an attacker that has stolen a valid code through a redirect can't make the client to exchange it to a token, as the client would not know the `code_verifier` for the code in the current context.

Is my reasoning correct? Am I missing some attack scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*My answer tries to give a short sum up of the most important information, based on [Daniel Fett's article "PKCE vs. Nonce: Equivalent or Not?"](https://danielfett.de/2020/05/16/pkce-vs-nonce-equivalent-or-not/). For a detailed descirption of attacker models and in-depth attack descriptions, please refert to this article.*

### Protection against CRSF and Code Injection

PKCE and `nonce` both protect against most CSRF attacks, but there are edge cases where `nonce` provides less security, c.f. the [previous mentioned article](https://danielfett.de/2020/05/16/pkce-vs-nonce-equivalent-or-not/#attacker-with-access-to-the-authorization-response).
While Nonce and PKCE provide both safety against code injection for confidential clients, public clients must use PKCE to protect against code injection.

### Why you might want to use an additional `nonce`

You may want to comply with the specification. Following the [OpenID Connect Core specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), the `nonce` is required for hybrid and implicit flow.

### Why you might want to use an additional `state`

The `state` provides security against attacker-forged error responses, which is not prevented by PKCE specification:

> When `state` is used for CSRF protection, OAuth error responses from the authorization endpoint must contain this parameter as well, providing protection against attacker-forged error responses. If only PKCE or Nonce are used for CSRF protection, error responses can be spoofed. [[df20](https://danielfett.de/2020/05/16/pkce-vs-nonce-equivalent-or-not/#special-case-error-responses)]

However, by simlpy returning the `code_challenge` on error, PKCE can be hardend against this attack.

### Attention using PKCE & `state` & `nonce` together!

It is totaly possible to use those three together, but there are some pitfalls regarding the verification.

> To avoid [sidestepping](https://danielfett.de/2020/05/16/pkce-vs-nonce-equivalent-or-not/#noncepkce-sidestep-attack) or [downgrading](https://danielfett.de/2020/05/16/pkce-vs-nonce-equivalent-or-not/#downgrade-attack-on-pkce) the PKCE and Nonce checks, authorization servers and clients need to agree on and continuously use one of the methods. For deployments with both OAuth and OIDC flows, PKCE should always be used and Nonce can be used additionally for OIDC flows.

The implementation of a combination is more complex and thus might easier lead to implementation errors. The parameter to verify needs to be choosen wisely for every situation and security goal.

Comment: I should have thought of looking at Daniel Fetts blog... Thank you very much!

Comment: So regular authorization code flow the most secure option is PKCE + state but PKCE alone can suffice?